# c# Moving data from one xaml to another xaml in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

It is a possibility to move data from one xaml to another xaml?

On MainPage I have textbox where I can write numbers and button which add "5" and navigate to Page1,
on Page1 I have textblock where I want to show result.

e.g
MainPage

textbox = 5, press button

Page1 
textblock = 10

I couldn't find any information about UWP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share data between pages by passing parameters.

```
var value = int.Parse(textbox.Text) + 5; // make sure you handle faulty input
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1), value);
```

and in `Page1`, you can access that value with this override:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    var value = (int)e.Parameter; // this should be 10

    // ... do what you need with that value
}
```